# click pay now in paypal page update my database too

Tags: php

I have a table to store my credit from user has been paid.

```
credit
  +id
  +amount
```

My goal is when you user click on button **pay now** in paypal page I have abiltity to  update my table the amount field.

Anybody know the ways to do this,

thanks

EDIT: look at this code

http://www.micahcarrick.com/04-19-2005/php-paypal-ipn-integration-class.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the button goes off to PayPal, you'll need to intercept the request first, either with AJAX, or send to a PHP script, and then send on through to PayPal.

Comment: @Alex.it's good ways : intercept the request first! how I can ?becuase it's in the paypal page.?
Thanks

Comment: If you use jQuery, attach a click event that AJAX's off to PHP. Or using PHP, if there are no post vars, you could use `header('Location: paypal.com/whatever')`. Otherwise, if you need to post, but don't need any feedback or user interaction, you could use cURL.

Answer (score 1):

PayPal's [Instant Payment Notification protocol](https://cms.paypal.com/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro) is usually what's used to do this.